# The uitableviewcell does not get updated until you scroll in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a standard `UITableView` where I create the cell as mentioned below. This works perfectly fine in iOS6 but on iOS7 the `detailTextLabel` does not get updated until I scroll and the cell that needs to be changed goes out of view.

While debugging it, I see that when i call `[tableview reloadData]`, it creates a new cell every time on ios7 whereas on ios6 it "deque(s)" the previously loaded cell so on calling `reloadData` it displays the updated text and removes the loading image as expected.
Why is the cell not getting "dequed" on ios7?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CEllId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"MainText";

    if (self.requestInProgress)
    {

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Processing...";

        // show loading spinner
        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = spinner;
        [spinner startAnimating];
    }
    else
    {
        // display the status
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"the text returned";

        // hide loading indicator & show disclosure indicator
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me. It should behave correctly. Is there something else in your code that could be affecting this?

Comment: What code executing when request finishes ?

Comment: What is the initial value of your self.requestInProgress? if the cell isn't reused then maybe your self.requestInProgress gets stuck at it's initial value and messes things. What the detailTextLabel text when you say its not updated. (P.S: make sure cell is not being reused by putting an NSLog in `if (self.requestInProgress)` and its else.)

Comment: Thank you for the replies, really appreciate that. The culprit was in the base view controller that it this class was getting inherited from.

Comment: In my case, the problem was that the class that i have the UiTableView gets inherited from a baseviewController class that was setting the tableView to nil every time on reload. 
Adding the tableView to a it's own tableviewController fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that the class that the `UITableView` inherits from a `baseviewController` class that was setting the `tableView` to `nil` every time on reload.

Adding the `tableView` to a it's own `tableViewController` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine. I think issue with height of the cell. you just fix the height cell. Then it will work fine. 
Method Name : **heightForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CEllId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"MainText";

    if (YES)
    {

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Processing...";

        // show loading spinner
        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = spinner;
        [spinner startAnimating];
    }
    else
    {
        // display the status
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"the text returned";

        // hide loading indicator & show disclosure indicator
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have a few different cells I was displaying in my table view (with varying heights) and I didn't set heightForRowAtIndexPath. Setting this correctly fixed my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tableview cell is not completely visible in the view. In that case
you can use `[cell setNeedsDisplay];`
for example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell setNeedsDisplay];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:yourView];
        });
```

Hope this works for you.